# spend bitcoins with python

Tags: python, bitcoin

I try to make simple bitcoin payment. I use python-bitcoinlib. I am able to send bitcoins to an address using **rpc.sendtoaddress(addr, 0.001 * COIN)**. I dont understand what address sent payments from? Is it automatically chosen one of my addresses? Can somebody explain it? Can I somehow specify which address I want to use for spending?

If I have HD wallet and bunch of addresses with every order in eshop. Is there is an elegant way how to transfer all these small payment to one address? Can someone recommend a python library for spending bitcoins or good resource for explanation (I dont want to tackle with low level transactions)?

Comment: the question should go in  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

**sendtoaddress** method always debits the default account.  [more details](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained)